# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message with Example Embed from discord.js guide

Tags: discord.js, embed

I just used example code for embed from here https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor and I am getting
`DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Here is how its looking in my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

client.on('message', async message => {
  

  if (message.content === `${prefix}ranking`) {
    // inside a command, event listener, etc.
    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
        .setDescription('Some description here')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        )
        .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png');

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
  }
  
});
```

Comment: what discord.js version are you using?

Comment: If you using discord.js v13 then change from `client.on('message', async message => {` to `client.on('messageCreate', async message => {`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for this answer but I think the second field in addFields (the \u200B caracter) is invalid or do an empty string. Try to replace it with another string.

You can also try to reply to the message at the end:

```
message.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] })
```